# How I can create text to Speech app with my own voice data?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to create a text to speech application in android studio with my own voice not Google voice data but i don't know how to do it.
I searched for some sources but i didn't find. i hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

As a primitive solution, save your sound for all words on dictionary. Split text into words and run voice files accordingly and sequentially. Your voice tones should be adjusted according to sentence. This is further work.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to download a special program and then pronounce evry sylable and word. I personally recomend you to use https://www.vocalware.com/index/demo
It's a program that will give you voice